# how to use pycharm configuration page?

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest

My python2 command line is: 
    "pytest --env=ver01 --service=driving -v -prod-db1 -s ( directoy to my testscript). If wish to run this in pycharm, where do I enter all those parameter? I know I can go - run/debug configuration, do I put the entire line into "parameter" area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to run/debug configuration

Click on green colored '+' button that is for "Add new Configuration "

Select Python-tests > py.test

Enter path to your script to Target Input.

Enable key `options` (It's a checkbox) and give parameters into it.

Refer this snapshot.

[image]